# Test mutple tags if value is empty with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Subjects>
  <Subject>
    <Title>Mr</Title>
    <Firstname></Firstname>
    <Surname></Surname>
    <Email></Email>
    <Incidents>
      <Incident>
        <ReferenceNo>meuen</ReferenceNo>
      </Incident>
    </Incidents>
    <TelephoneNos />
    <Employers />
    <BankAccounts />
  </Subject>
  <Subject>
    <Title>Mr</Title>
    <Firstname>Test</Firstname>
    <Surname>Test</Surname>
    <Email>test@test.com</Email>
    <Incidents>
      <Incident>
        <ReferenceNo>jkcsdlkjsdl</ReferenceNo>
      </Incident>
    </Incidents>
    <TelephoneNos />
    <Employers />
    <BankAccounts />
  </Subject>
</Subjects>
```

I need to check if either if the ReferenceNo fields are empty using XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Result xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

            <xsl:for-each select="/Subjects/Subject">

                <xsl:variable name="output" select="Incidents/Incident/ReferenceNo"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($output) > 0">
                        <Response>Y</Response>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Response>N</Response>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </Result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this only checks the first node and not both or all of the ReferenceNo tags.

How can I accomplish this result.

I have tried it in a xsl:foeach this will obviously repeat my tag1 and tag2 nodes twice in the instance of the above XML

I want `response` to be a value of Y if either of the tags are populated and N if neither are populated

This is the current response that I am getting

```
<Result xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:x="http://tempuri.org/">
   <Response>Y</Response>
   <Response>Y</Response>
</Result>
```

I do not want `Response` to be repeated

Comment: What should be a true result of the test: (1) all `ReferenceNo` are empty, or (2) at least one  `ReferenceNo` is empty?

Comment: I've made a few edits to the post, does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test:

```
<xsl:when test="Subjects/Subject/Incidents/Incident/ReferenceNo[string-length() > 0]">
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:when test="Subjects/Subject/Incidents/Incident/ReferenceNo[text()]">
```

will return true when there is at least one non-empty `ReferenceNo` element.

The test can (and should) be applied from the context of the `/` root node. There is no need for an `xsl:for-each` instruction.